# in manjaro xfce, how can I change my forgotten password? if I still have access to the system

Tags: arch-linux, password-recovery, manjaro

I have a laptop that I have not used for many months, this laptop was for a friend and I only remember the encryption password that I put since the installation is the one that he asks me before grub.

The user's password is the same for root but I chose the option not to ask for it at startup, so when I put the luks encryption I can go directly to the xfce desktop.

My problem is that I forget the user password, so if the screen locks it asks me for it or if I want to do sudo it asks me for it.

Is there a way that from the terminal I can rescue it, or know where ligthtdm saves it, since at the beginning it does not require it.?

o Any tool to autocrack my password?

Comment: Boot from an bootable USB drive, chroot into existing installation, use `passwd <user>` to change password.

Comment: When did you encrypt one? Was it during the *installation*?